# Extracting sub string of a string in python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, string

I have a stream of structured strings. I want to extract 2 specific sections from each of them in Python language.

> **For example)** my Strings are looking like these:
>
> cpe:2.3:a:**troglobit**:**uftpd**:*:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
>
> cpe:2.3:o:**google**:**android**:8.0:*:*:*:*:*:*:*
>
> cpe:2.3:a:**microsoft**:**asp.net_core**:2.1:*:*:*:*:*:*
>
> I need the BOLD sections only.

Be aware that in the end the number of `*` is different in each case (it's between 6,7,8). Also, the strings could be started by `cpe:2.3:o:` or `cpe:2.3:a:`

I have tried different expressions such as these:

For example, this one works with cases that only have 6 `*` at the end.

```
try:
                        temp = re.search("cpe:2.3:a:(.*):\*:\*:\*:\*:\*:\*",testString).group(1)
except AttributeError:
                        temp = 'NOT FOUND'
```

Or

(Does not work)

```
try:
                        temp = re.search("(cpe:2.3:a:(.*)|cpe:2.3:o:)(.*)(:\*:\*:\*:\*:\*:\*:\*:\*|:\*:\*:\*:\*:\*:\*:\*|:\*:\*:\*:\*:\*:\*)", testString).group(1)
except AttributeError:
                        temp = 'NOT FOUND'
```

Or

(Does not work)

```
 try:    
                        temp = re.search("(cpe:2.3:a:(.*):(.*))':{0}'$", testString).group(1)
 except AttributeError:
                        temp = 'NOT FOUND'
```

Thank You.

Comment: all lines have cpe:2.3:a: or something like this always? I mean a 3 alphabet character then a : then a number, a dot, another number, another :, another character and another :? if yes check https://regex101.com/r/JKJ312/1

Comment: @HamedGhasempour This works too. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it without a `regex`

```
sample = 'cpe:2.3:a:microsoft:asp.net_core:2.1:*:*:*:*:*:*'

' '.join(sample.split(':')[3:][:2])
```

`'microsoft asp.net_core'`